# Why does the File class return an object of type '_File' instead of 'File' in Dart/Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-io

[image]

[image]
There isn't much else to be said. I created a blank project with no dependencies to test this.

Code to copy if you want to run it yourself:

```
import 'dart:io';

void main() {
  File testFile = File('test');
  print('testFile: $testFile');
  print('testFile type: ${testFile.runtimeType}');
  print(testFile.runtimeType == File);
  print('');
}
```

Edit: upgraded flutter to 2.8.0, same problem persists.

Comment: `testFile is File` will be `true`, and that's the proper way to check object types.  In general, you shouldn't rely on `runtimeType` (especially for classes you don't control) since it could be some derived class.

Comment: @jamesdlin the other answer technically directly answers my question, but yours was even more helpful. thanks for interpreting what I really needed to know!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`File` is abstract class. `_File` is implement of `File`. so on this case runtimeType of testFile is `_Type`.

```
@pragma("vm:entry-point")
abstract class File implements FileSystemEntity {
  /// Creates a [File] object.
  ///
  /// If [path] is a relative path, it will be interpreted relative to the
  /// current working directory (see [Directory.current]), when used.
  ///
  /// If [path] is an absolute path, it will be immune to changes to the
  /// current working directory.
  @pragma("vm:entry-point")
  factory File(String path) {
    final IOOverrides? overrides = IOOverrides.current;
    if (overrides == null) {
      return new _File(path);
    }
    return overrides.createFile(path);
  }
```